# Unable to run ionic app on android device

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

```
C:\Users\Saurabh\demo\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                throw e;
                      ^



ERROR running one or more of the platforms: 
Error:    C:\Users\Saurabh\demo\platforms\android\cordova\run.bat:
Command failed with exit code 1
You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project.
```

However, when I emulate same app it is running without any issue. My environment info are as follows-

- Cordova CLI: 5.0.0
- Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.0
- Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.0
- Ionic Version: 1.0.0
- Ionic CLI Version: 1.5.0
- Ionic App Lib Version: 0.1.0
- OS: Windows 8.1
- Node Version: v0.12.2

PS: I have already tried to remove and add platform.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEro9.png

Comment: Please copy your www directory to newly created phonegap app and reinstall all plugins and platform it will work correctly. 
T

Answer (score 2):

I think you don't have set properly Environment Variable on windows , For example

**Java JDK**

create an environment variable for **JAVA_HOME** pointing to the root folder where the Java JDK was installed. So, if you installed the JDK into ***C:\Program Files\Java\jdk7***, set **JAVA_HOME** to be this path. After that, add the JDK's bin directory to the PATH variable as well. Following the previous assumption, this should be either ***%JAVA_HOME%\bin*** or the full path ***C:\Program Files\Java\jdk7\bin***

**Apache Ant**

you'd want to add this to your PATH: ***C:\apache-ant-1.9.2\bin***

**Android SDK**

Cordova requires the **ANDROID_HOME** environment variable to be set. This should point to the [ANDROID_SDK_DIR]\android-sdk directory (for example ***c:\android\android-sdk***).
Next, update your PATH to include the **tools/** and **platform-tools/** folder in that folder. So, using **ANDROID_HOME**, you would add both ***%ANDROID_HOME%\tools*** and ***%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools***

For more details go to [here](http://santoshshinde2012.blogspot.in/2015/05/basic-of-starts-with-ionic-framework.html)...

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have the npm module `q` installed, install it like this (from the project root folder):

```
npm install q
```

Add `--save` to it to add it to the dependencies in `package.json`